# Executing typed Rofi command, not what is selected?

Tags: rofi

Is there a way to execute the typed command in Rofi, instead of what is highlighted? I'm having an issue where I'm trying to execute `gnome-screenshot -a`, but Rofi keeps selecting `gnome-screenshot -d 2`, a command I had run some time in the past, out of the list of possible commands. I know I could delete the history, but surely there is a way to run the command written rather than the command selected?